# Lubuntu 16.04.3 LTS logout button not working

Tags: lubuntu, shutdown, logout

Lubuntu 16.04.3 LTS logout button (the button that normally brings up a menu to shutdown, switch users, logout, etc.) does nothing; was working properly since installed about 1 week ago. The Shutdown button on lower right corner is not working either. The only way to shutdown is to hold down the power button. Restarting after this debacle reveals no obvious system complaints. However, I note that if I sign in as Guest, all is fine; I can shutdown, logoff, change users (but then not logout, shutdown, or switch users once I'm in my normal admin account). Operation is otherwise okay. What say all?

Updated information: I shutdown the system for a more extended period of time (say, 15 min) instead of the roughly 30 seconds I had been waiting. When I started it up and logged into my normal account, the logout button on the menu worked. I opened up the normal window to allow me to shutdown, logout, switch users, etc. The shutdown button on the lower right side still does nothing, however (I don't normally shutdown with this button, so for all I know it never worked). In any case, no problem, right?

Not so fast.

The taskbar regressed to the default setup. The application launcher no longer had the application icons I'd added to it. The sound volume icon was not in the same place. The clock's format had gone to it's crummy default setup from my obviously superior format. Most obvious, though, is the fact that the icons went back to the default 24x24 size (I'm a 48x48 man myself). I guess fixing this is little to complain about.

That said, what's going on here? As I see it, there's some sort of configuration file somewhere that the system uses to set up the taskbar. Somehow, it got corrupted and so when I clicked on the logout button the system didn't know it was supposed to do something. After shutting down for an extended period and then restarting, the system disliked the corrupted anonymous configuration file and got so fed up it loaded the default file instead. 'Zat about it? If so, is this a congenital problem with this distro? Furthermore, what's the config file here that got corrupted? If this happens a lot, I might as well back it up.

Thoughts?

Comment: When you have problems with a frozen desktop environment, or as in your case, that the shutdown/reboot does not work, you can use **"SysRq R E I S U B"**. SysRq is usually activated via `alt` + `PrtScreen` (that you keep pressed while slowly pressing the keys R E I S U B, one key after another). See this link, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key. This way you get a *soft reboot* and decrease the risk to corrupt the file system.

Comment: ... and the problems might be caused by corruption because some configuration file was not saved in a correct way. I am running Lubuntu 16.04 LTS and it works well for me. -- Sometimes it it possible to repair a corrupt file system according to the following link, http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2196858&p=13409986#post13409986. But the best alternatives are: 1. Frequent backups, so that you can restore to a working system without losing many current files and 2. Careful operations to avoid hard shutdown/reboot.